# Can I travel to Belarus or Ukraine with a valid Russian visa?

Tags: visas, russia, ukraine, syrian-citizens, belarus

Can I travel to Belarus or Ukraine with a valid Russian tourist visa?.

I'm a Syrian citizen.

Comment: Are you asking whether _having_ a Russian visa (in addition to one for Ukraine, of course) will create trouble for you at the border, given the not-exactly-chummy current Russia-Ukraine relations?

Answer (score 11):

No, and you should not generally expect countries to accept visas issued by other countries.

Ukraine requires Syrian citizens to obtain a visa, which is, as usual, done at a Ukrainian embassy or consulate. [Ukrainian visa requirements are here,](http://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entering-ukraine/visa-requirements-for-foreigners) there is no provision for entering with a visa issued by Russia or any other foreign country.

Belarus likewise requires Syrian citizens to obtain a visa (unless you have a diplomatic Syrian passport), and the Belarusian [MFA page on visas](http://mfa.gov.by/visa/) ([English version](http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/)) explicitly states that no visas issued by other countries are accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Since 2020-07-01, you can visit Belarus with a Russian visa and vice versa.  See [Russia, Belarus sign agreement on mutual recognition of each other's visas](https://tass.com/economy/1169807).

You cannot visit Ukraine with a Russian visa, unless you also have a Ukrainian visa.

See also [this post about border crossings](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158120/2509) between Russia and Belarus.

Warning as of 2020-07-07: [another source](https://reform.by/144652-soglashenie-belarusi-i-rossii-o-priznanii-viz-vstupit-v-silu-k-koncu-goda) in Russian, dated 2020-07-01, states it will take several more months until it *actually* takes force.  These sources contradict each other.  Either it's already in force, or it will be soon (and as of July 2020, the 2019-2021 Coronavirus Pandemic means few travellers should make the overland EU-Belarus-Russia trip anyway, with the Russia-Belarus border apparently closed for everybody).