# Difficulties during trip from Poland to Russia via Belarus

Tags: trains, international-travel, russia, belarus

I have an EU citizenship and I want to travel by train from Warsaw, Poland to Moscow, Russia. 
I know that I need both Russian and Belarussian visas, but I have heard from some people that a few months ago there were difficulties during crossing BY-RU border by train, and some people had even got entry refusal.

Has anyone heard of such problems? Is everything okay now or not?

Comment: at the moment you cant cross the Russia Belarus border as there is no immigration control even if you have Russian and Belorussian visas. When are you going? Russia and Belarus will soon offer a scheme where visas for either country are valid in both, so it will be like the Schengen area. https://belarusfeed.com/belarus-russia-visa-recognition-rules/

Comment: Is your train direct or will you change trains within Belarus?  It may matter.

Comment: @BritishSam Other sources such as linked by mdeweys answer disagree.

Comment: @gerrit the scheme mentioned in my comment must be running

Comment: @BritishSam [I have asked here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/141811/2509), but reportedly even before this is in force, travellers were allowed on direct trains from EU to Russia.  Looks like [it's not in force yet](https://eng.belta.by/society/view/rapota-belarus-russia-visa-recognition-agreement-ready-awaits-political-decision-122598-2019/) (article from today which implies it is not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current position appears to be confused. According to the Man in Seat 61 you can cross the border by train as long as you started outside Belarus (which you state you plan to do) but international travellers cannot pick up a train in Belarus and travel to Russia. You do need the right visas too of course.

https://www.seat61.com/Russia.htm#London%20to%20Minsk

If you do make the journey I am sure he would appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Since 2020-07-01, the situation has changed, as [Russia and Belarus have signed a visa agreement](https://tass.com/economy/1169807) and should now recognise each others visas.  Your Russian visa is now enough to visit or transit Belarus, and you should no longer need a separate visa.  See also [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158120/2509) for more details on the Russia-Belarus border.

Warning as of 2020-07-07: [another source](https://reform.by/144652-soglashenie-belarusi-i-rossii-o-priznanii-viz-vstupit-v-silu-k-koncu-goda) in Russian, dated 2020-07-01, states it will take several more months until it *actually* takes force.  These sources contradict each other.  Either it's already in force, or it will be soon (and as of July 2020, the 2019-2021 Coronavirus Pandemic means few travellers should make the overland EU-Belarus-Russia trip anyway).