# Is it possible at present to get by rail from the EU into Russia?

Tags: trains, europe, russia

I wonder if there's still a way of getting into mainland Russia (not the Kaliningrad exclave) from the EU by rail.

- Travelling via Ukraine is out of question due to multiple reasons.
- Travelling via Belarus is out of question, because 3rd party nationals are not allowed to cross the Belarus-Russia land border  (that means by train, car, bus or on foot; flying from Minsk to Moscow is okay for foreigners since May 2017).
- AFAIK, services from Finland have been suspended.

How about Estonia and Latvia? Are there any passenger rail services crossing the border into Russia?

Comment: " 3rd party nationals are not allowed to cross the Belarus-Russia land border." That's not true... at least before Covid and the war (I cannot find anything that says this has been changed). You may need a transit visa and must ask for a migration card though. But at the present there is no direct rail connection way.

Comment: @xngtng Unfortunately it's very true and confirmed by multiple sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus%E2%80%93Russia_border

In short, the Union State of Russia and Belarus is like a Schengen Area, in which only its citizens can move freely, foreigners are confined to one single member country...

Comment: Here's another source: https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294447-i5625-k11403630-Crossing_belarus_russian_border_for_foreigners-Belarus.html If you have opposite information, please go ahead! I'd be very happy to hear that this weird situation has been resolved.

Comment: Aha, https://www.russianrail.com/news/crossing-russia---belarus-border-by-train it did change after 2016/7. Although I guess in practice the checks are random and migration cards by Belarus is usually recognized in Russia, but indeed technically illegal. It is legal in the other direction with trains (but not cars), as Belarus registration authorities usually accept rail tickets as proof of entry.

Comment: Yes, crossing into BLR is reportedly less of a problem, Belarusian officials are more lenient. Regarding entering Russia, travellers report that by car or bus it's not possible at all, by train it could be done, but the risk of fine or detention is not what an ordinary traveller would want to experience.

Comment: Have you considered getting a train from Kalingrad?

Comment: @Xnero IMO that's not going to help me. By boarding a Russia-bound train in Kaliningrad (or even in Vilnius, Lithuania - to make it easier for a Westerner), I'd face the same issues while crossing the Belarus-Russia border...

Comment: Do you specifically need rail? There are busses from Tallinn to Saint Petersburg.

Comment: @jcaron No I don't. Just asking. Thx for the suggestion.

Comment: I travelled via Belarus in 2019 and it was no problem at all, and a popular route too.  Also, [since 2020](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/141811/2509), Russia and Belarus recognise each others visas, so you should be able to cross into Belarus and Russia with a Russian visa.  Probably it will change again soon after Russia annexes Belarus and Belarus ceases to exist…

Comment: @gerrit I've read many stories about foreigners who successfully entered Russia from Belarus overland, especially by train, but I can't find any official source stating that this is allowed. On the other hand, I found several official sources stating that this is not allowed and that perpetrators could face punishment: https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/russia/entry-requirements

Comment: @Johnnyjanko It has always worked for direct trains from the EU to Russia, and the linked gov.uk page says "contact your train or tour operator"; at the time I received a Belarus transit visa and Russian tourist visa from the same tour operator, who confirmed this is allowed for direct tains.  There are no such trains at the moment, so the question is moot.  I also wonder how the [Russia-Belarus visa union](https://www.fragomen.com/insights/russiabelarus-mutual-visa-recognition.html) affects things — the gov.uk page does not seem to consider this information yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Some train services were already suspended because of covid related travel restrictions and the few still operating services (e.g. from Helsinki to St. Petersburg) were suspended because of the war. Not necessarily because land travel is prohibited, but due to lack of demand.

Comment: On a side note, are there nowadays any passenger rail services between Poland and Belarus? I can't find any in the European railway timetables.

Comment: It's not lack of demand (quite the opposite), it was a request of the Finnish government https://yle.fi/a/3-12375838

Comment: @Johnnyjanko No, there aren't.